# Grid - Get all surrounding cells using specified area size

Tags: c#

I have a simple 2d grid, I want to be able to get all surrounding cells of a specific cell, given an area-size. Currently, my code only successfully handles the directly adjacent cells and returns that area of 3x3, if I try a larger area, I run into issues:

```
public static class DIRECTION
{
    public static Coord NORTH = new Coord(0, 1);
    public static Coord SOUTH = new Coord(0, -1);
    public static Coord EAST = new Coord(1, 0);
    public static Coord WEST = new Coord(-1, 0);

    public static Coord NORTHEAST = new Coord(1, 1);
    public static Coord NORTHWEST = new Coord(-1, 1);
    public static Coord SOUTHEAST = new Coord(1, -1);
    public static Coord SOUTHWEST = new Coord(-1, -1);
}

public List<Cell> GetSurroundingCells(Coord current, GridLayer layer, int areaSize)
    {
        bool IsSurrounding(Coord coord, Coord dir)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= areaSize; i++)
            {
                if (coord.Equals(current.Add(new Coord(dir.x * i, dir.z * i))))
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        List<Cell> cells = new List<Cell>();

        for (int x = 0; x < GetWidth(); x++)
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < GetHeight(); z++)
            {
                Coord coord = new Coord(x, z);

                if (IsSurrounding(coord, DIRECTION.NORTH) ||
                    IsSurrounding(coord, DIRECTION.SOUTH) ||
                    IsSurrounding(coord, DIRECTION.EAST) ||
                    IsSurrounding(coord, DIRECTION.WEST) ||
                    IsSurrounding(coord, DIRECTION.NORTHEAST) ||
                    IsSurrounding(coord, DIRECTION.NORTHWEST) ||
                    IsSurrounding(coord, DIRECTION.SOUTHEAST) ||
                    IsSurrounding(coord, DIRECTION.SOUTHWEST))
                    cells.Add(GetCell(coord, layer));
            }
        }

        return cells;
    }
```

As you can see I already try to manage area size, but lets say I give my function an `areaSize` of 2, it would return the following area:

[image]

I obviusly want all the cells in the image above to be returned, but since I'm simply multiplying my directions, some cells will not be accounted for, how can I make sure all cells in the area are returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a generic method that takes a start `row`, `column` and `distance` to search.

Here is a lightly modified version of something I've used in the past.

```
public static List<Cell> SurroundingCellss(int startRow, int startColumn, int distance)
{
    List<Cell> matches = new List<Cell>();

    for (int searchRow = startRow - distance; searchRow <= startRow + distance; searchRow++)
    {
        for (int searchCol = startColumn - distance; searchCol <= startColumn + distance; searchCol++)
        {
            if (cells[searchRow, searchCol] != null)
            {
                //do logic and if ok add to return list
                matches.Add(cells[searchRow, searchCol]);
            }
        }
    }
    return matches;
}
```

You will need to edit it for your needs but gives you an idea.